# NSTreeNode parentNode method never returns nil

Tags: cocoa, treenode

I am using bindings with a NSOutlineView and NSTreeController. I am trying to determine the parent node of a particular node by using the -parentNode method of NSTreeNode, however the method never returns nil as indicated in the documentation. Instead I have to do this in order to make things work. The introspection is a hack. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
NSTreeNode *parentNode = [[[treeController selectedNodes] objectAtIndex:0] parentNode];
LXNode *realParentNode = [parentNode representedObject];

if (parentNode && [realParentNode isKindOfClass:[LXNode class]])
{
    //The parent exists

}
else
{
   //Parent does not exist.
}
```

In debugger shows parentNode as follows

```
> parentNode           0x001a1e50 
> NSObject             {...} 
> _childNodesProxy     0x0 
> _representedObject   0x10019f500 
> _observationInfo     0x0 
> _reserved2           0x0 
> _childNodes          0x1020b6d10 
> _parentNode          0x0 
> _NSTreeNodeFlags     {...}
```

Comment: OK, it's not returning `nil`; what *is* it returning?

Comment: Well its a bit cryptic, but this is what I get from the debugger. Any suggestions. Thanks.

parentNode               0x001a1e50
   NSObject                 {...}
   _childNodesProxy         0x0
   _representedObject       0x10019f500
   _observationInfo         0x0
   _reserved2               0x0
   _childNodes              0x1020b6d10
   _parentNode              0x0
   _NSTreeNodeFlags         {...}

Comment: Perhaps you should edit that into your question to preserve formatting. Also, what if you log `parentNode` using `NSLog`?

Comment: Thanks for helping out so far. If I may ask, how am I suppose to NSLog an object other than an NSString?

Comment: NSLog doesn't just take a string; it takes a *format* string and zero or more arguments, which must conform to the types you promise in the format string. See the string formatting docs: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I can stuff a pointer (%p) into a formatted string. So I did it and I got this,  0x100397130 (which tells me that parentNode is not nil). This is the same result as displayed by the debugger.